# Signal Processing research: Was matter ever learnt?

Tags: experimental-physics

I understand that every **energy** in our universe can act as a *wave* or as a *mass*.

If I understand correctly, the scientific and engineeric field of *signal processing* generally deals with **signals from** *wave energy*, but were signals from *matter energy* ever learnt and if so what would be a typical example?

Comment: Relativistically, mass and energy are equivalent so the difference is superficial. But for signal processing it is entirely moot whether the signal is transmitted by a wave or by transport of matter, it concerns the pattern transmitted, not the nature of its carrier.

Comment: The pattern transmitted, an answer with two examples (I guess?) such as "discrete" and "sequential" is maybe the answer to my question (if would example matter sampling in a signal processing fashion).